# If I rub an antistatic bag all over my body, would that stop unwanted static discharge?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-rec, static-discharge

If I rub an antistatic bag all over my body, would that be good enough to de-static-ify myself before handling a motherboard and CPU?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.


Comment: No, since the plastic is ungrounded, you will build up a charge and will actually create the problem. There's no magic to it, you ground yourself with a proper anti-static strap or create a ground plane of equal potential if you do not have an available ground, set everything on it and ground yourself to it.

Comment: +1 for posting a question about discharing after something having been rubbed all over your body :-)

Answer (score 10):

It would actually have probably NO effect.

Anti-static bags are not anti like anti-gravity is anti to gravity. Anti Static prevents the transfer of static or ESD, it does not destroy energy. Rubbing your body with anti-static bags would mean the static on you would be reflected back on you.

In short, its about the least effective method I can think of to reduce your bodies ES buildup. Just ground yourself on the chassis like the rest of us.

Comment: By least effective I think you mean not effective at all